# I have couple of folders in SVN which I want to lock from other users to avoid accidental commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have couple of folders in SVN which I want to lock from other users to avoid accidental commit , How lock files but and lock a folder , I am using tortoiseSVN (TortoiseSVN 3.6.0 version)

Please help on this.
Its very priority.

Regards,
Nageswari

Comment: Do you have control of the server, i.e. can you temporarily add ACLs to the folder?

Comment: Maybe its VisualSVN Server **3.6.0**? There is no TortoiseSVN version 3.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Read Only user permissions to your repositories, projects or even individual directories or files. See the [Getting Started | Configuring User Permissions](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions) page and the [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) article.

PS I guess that you use VisualSVN Server since you mention version 3.6.0. There is no such TortoiseSVN version, but there was VisualSVN Server 3.6.0. BTW, version 3.6.0 is no longer supported and you should consider upgrading to the latest 3.9.x builds. See the release announcement at https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/upgrade-to-subversion-1.10